# How to achieve certificate based authentication with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS Cognito as an authentication method for my cloud application. I didn't find any forum addressing this.
If I am correct, AWS Cognito doesn't use public key certificates?
Is there a workaround or a method to still get a Cognito public key certificate?
Does anyone have a solution to my question how to achieve certificate-based authentication with AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AWS Cognito as an authentication method for my cloud application. . I didn't find any forum addressing this

I believe the the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/index.html#lang/en_us) is quite comprehensive. You can use AWS Cognito simple as an OAuth 2.0 IdP

> AWS Cognito doesn't use public key certificates?

No, it doesn't

> how to achieve certificate-based authentication with AWS Cognito?

You will need to federated the authentication with a provider, which does.

AWS Cognito can be federated using SAML with an external IdP (it is considered as an enterprise feature so it costs something, check the current pricing, I recall it was around $0.5 / MAU (monthly authenticated user) )

I am not sure if there is a cloud provider directly supporting X509 based user authentication, you may setup your own SAML based identity server (there are a few product supporting X509 authentication, from small and easy SimpleSAMLphp to full identity servers such as WSO2 Identitiy Server, ForgeRock IAM or your corporate AD)

Comment: https://medium.com/@gayanmadusanka_80721/login-to-aws-console-from-wso2-identity-server-cb05d4d12ff5